# Do I Need Composer, Git or Any of These after Project Is Finished?

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php

For example:

I have a Homestead with Laravel in Virtual Machine. After I finish my project could I just copy the files and bring them to my Wamp server, and export the database and import it into Wamp?

Or is there more behind all this?

Comment: `One does not simply "finish" a project.`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you understand what i meant...

Comment: By making life harder for yourself, no you don't "need" git or composer if you have all the files of a working installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, generally this could be one way to deploy a project to a server.

The question is a bit broad to give a good answer because there are many ways how to built a good project deploy chain. First of all it depends on the server you are deploying to and the access rights you have (e.g. are you allowed to ssh into the server or can you run git at your server).

If you have ssh access and you are able to run git a good way could be to pull the git project from your git server, run `composer install` and migrate and seed your database with artisan.

There are even more ways up to full integrated deploy chains where you just need to push your project to a git server to trigger a deploy (e.g have a look at [Capistrano](https://www.airpair.com/laravel/posts/automating-laravel-deployments-using-capistrano) or [Laravel Forge](https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploy-php-apps-easily-with-laravel-forge) for automated deploy).